# Lavarel Illuminate class for mail reset not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, illuminate-container

I made a notification class as `MailResetPasswordNotification` and edited the mail representation of the notification with the following.

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $link = url("/password/reset/?token=".$this->token);

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->view('reset.emailer')
        ->from('info@example.com')
        ->subject('Reset your password')
        ->line("Hey, We've successfully changed the text ")
        ->action('Reset Password', $link)
        ->attach('reset.attachment')
        ->line('Thank you!');
}
```

I also found the file for resetting password in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Auth/Passwords/CanResetPassword.php` and overrode it with mine like:

```php
namespace Illuminate\Auth\Passwords;

use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword as MailResetPasswordNotification;

trait CanResetPassword
{
    public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new App\Notifications\MailResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error.

> Class 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\App\Notifications\MailResetPasswordNotification' not found

Comment: Where is your file `CanResetPassword.php` is located?

Comment: you do **NOT** edit files in `vendor` ... just override the method on your model and you have to reference the class correctly (namespacing)

Comment: How to override method that is located just in vendor? Can't find it anywhere?@lagbox

Comment: have you tried `composer dump` ?

Comment: you define the method on your model which overrides the version from the trait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a method `sendPasswordResetNotification` in a class that implements `CanResetPassword`